# What source control systems support triggers

Tags: version-control

One of the nice things about ClearCase was that it supported triggers. When users performed certain operations (check-ins, merges, etc) I could have the system automatically run a script.

What other source control systems offer this capability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion (SVN), Mercurial (hg), git, darcs, and bzr all do.

In SVN, hg, bzr, and darcs they are called hooks.

git and CSV call them triggers.

Comment: Subversion also calls them _hooks_

Comment: Git, triggers? Never heard those two together before. They are called hooks in git as well. If you don't know about a particular vcs, why do you just guess??

Answer (score 2):

Subversion allows you to write "triggers" (it calls them hooks). They are generally written on the shell language of your system, but obviously you can install your language of choice and call out to it.

You can do it in TFS as well, but you have to prat around with web-services, so it's all a palaver.

I would imagine most decent VCSs will - everything but SourceSafe probably!!!

Answer (score 0):

Note: the successor of ClearCase is [Jazz source control](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/c_getting_started.html) (used within [RTC - Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/projects/rational-team-concert/)), and it supports triggers as well.

Comment: See https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_intro.html